# How to convert factor inside a dataframe to numeric?

Tags: r

Consider the str of dataframe, example, below:

```
 $ A                : num 0.00606
 $ B                : num 0.00466
 $ C                : num 0.00746
 $ D    : Factor w/ 2 levels "-0.04","D": 1
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "Tilt"
 $ E   : Factor w/ 2 levels " 0.00","E": 1
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "Tilt"
```

How do I convert it such that it becomes:

```
 $ A                : num 0.00606
 $ B                : num 0.00466
 $ C                : num 0.00746
 $ D                : num -0.04
 $ E                : num -0.00
```

Comment: `df$D <- as.numeric(as.character(df$D)))`

Comment: Thanks Adam - is there any way to not need to specify the column that needs to be converted, but instead automatically convert those that are factor?

Comment: Could you please `dput()` your dataframe?

Comment: Try this: `df[ sapply(df, is.factor)] <- lapply(df[ sapply(df, is.factor)], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))`